# How to install packages offline using ubuntu 14.04.3 kickstart

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, iso-image, custom-installation

I am trying to install additional packages in ubuntu using kickstart (without internet). I am currently using dpkg -i /location/to/mydeb/*.deb . The installer runs but fails to install packages. If i run apt-get install -f (without internet) post installation of ubuntu, everything works. Any help would be appreciated.

I am following this tutorial with some changes - http://gyk.lt/ubuntu-14-04-desktop-unattended-installation/ and little help from here - https://jack6liu.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/how-to-customize-ubuntu-14-04-installation-c/

Only difference is i wanna install some packages offline, so i put them with iso and run dpkg -i /media/cdrom/mydeb/*.deb in the %post section of ks.cfg

My ks.cfg - https://pastebin.com/vLCcfN3d

Answer (score 0):

```
%post
dpkg -i /location/to/mydeb/*.deb
apt-get -f install
%end
```

Comment: That's good to begin with but the problem i faced was some sort of gpg-key error when installing like that.

Comment: If it's like Redhat, there is a GPG check boolean somewhere you have to change.  Never encountered that problem on debian before.

Comment: i even added --no-check-gpg at the end but still gpg key error.